# Rails 3.2.8, sqlite3, ActiveRecord why does sort wrong way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, sqlite

I wrote two simple relation helpers:

- `with_preferred_sort_order` returns a relation
- `all_on_page` returns `[pages_count, record_array]`

with_preferred_sort_order sorts records strangily:

```
1.9.3p194 :040 > Article.with_preferred_sort_order.
all_on_page(1).last.map{|a| puts a.title[0..20]};nil
  (0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "articles" 
  Article Load (157.9ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" 
ORDER BY title Desc LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0

“The Bar for Success 
method_missing in Jav
jQuery on Rails: A Fr
jQuery in Action (w00
jQuery in Action (w00
jQuery Selector Refca
jQuery Selector Refca
jQuery Selector Refca
jQuery 1.4 and Malfor
jQuery 1.4 and Malfor
What’s Wrong with “HT
What’s Up With All Th
What’s Up With All Th
What’s Up With All Th
What’s Up With All Th
What’s New in Bundler
Vibrant Ink Theme for
Using the New Gem Bun
Using the New Gem Bun
Using SproutCore 2.0 
Using SproutCore 2.0 
Using SproutCore 2.0 
Using >= Considered H
Understanding “Protot
Understanding JavaScr
Tokaido: My Hopes and
Tokaido Status Update
Today’s Dispatch: Wea
Threads (in Ruby): En
Threads (in Ruby): En
Threads (in Ruby): En
The Rails 3 Router: R
The Rails 3 Router: R
The Irony of the iPad
Textmate gem
Textmate Search in a 
Stop Watching Sophie’
Spinning up a new Rai
Spinning up a new Rai
Some of the Problems 
Simplifying Rails Blo
Search within a folde
Ruby 2.0 Refinements 
Ruby 2.0 Refinements 
Ruby 2.0 Refinements 
RailsConf Talk Recap
RailsConf Slides
RailsConf Slides
RailsConf Slides
RailsConf Europe Slid
 => nil 
1.9.3p194 :041 >
```

Here is the source

```
  def self.included recipient
    with recipient do
      scope :with_preferred_sort_order, 
        lambda { 
          #sort_by  = recipient.preferences.sort_by; 
          #asc_desc = recipient.preferences.asc_desc; 
          #recipient.order("%s %s"%[sort_by, asc_desc]) 
          sort_by  = preferences.sort_by; 
          asc_desc = preferences.asc_desc; 
          order("%s %s"%[sort_by, asc_desc]) 
        }
    end
  end
```

And onother one

```
module ActiveRecord
  class Relation
    # Returns an array [ pages_range, items_array]
    #   pages_range is a range of pages, which starts from 1, e.g. 1..19
    #   items_array is an array which contains items of page_number page
    #
    def all_on_page page_number=1, items_per_page=nil
      def total_pages items_qty, items_per_page
        r = items_qty/items_per_page
        r == 0 ? 1 : items_qty % items_per_page !=0 ? r+1 : r
      end

      items_per_page ||= self.klass.respond_to?(:preferences) ? 
        self.klass.preferences.items_per_page.to_i : 10
      items_qty = self.count

      pages_range = 1..total_pages(items_qty, items_per_page)
      offset      = (page_number - 1)*items_per_page
      items_array = self.offset(offset).limit(items_per_page).all

      [ pages_range, items_array ]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: It might help to add an explanation of what you were expecting.

Comment: I expect titles to be sorted alphabetically strarting from " and ending with W. But as you can see they are sorted not alphabetically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here:

1. The first entry begins with a non-ASCII character (not sure what exactly it is, but it's not a standard double quote). I believe those get sorted last after the standard ASCII characters.
2. You appear to want your entries sorted from A to Z, but your SQL specifies `ORDER BY title Desc`, which will sort descending from Z to A. You want an ascending sort (`ORDER BY title ASC` or just `ORDER BY title`). This is also why the above non-ASCII character showed up at the top rather than the bottom.
3. It's not specified, but it sounds like you may be expecting the sort to be case-insensitive. The standard collating sequence in SQLite is BINARY, which sorts based on the ASCII values. Since upper case letters have lower ASCII values than lower case, all your titles that start with an upper case letter will be sorted before all the titles that start with lower case.

Have a read through [SQLite's documentation on collating sequences](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#collation). In order to make the titles sort in a case-insensitive manner, you'll want to use the NOCASE collating sequence, either by adding it to the SELECT:

```
...ORDER BY title COLLATE NOCASE...
```

Or by adding the `COLLATE NOCASE` statement into that column in the table definition. If you want to fold the non-ASCII characters into the sequence somewhere, you may need to define a custom collating sequence.

Comment: _It's not specified, but it sounds like you may be expecting the sort to be case-insensitive..._ Yes, exactly! Thank you!